# Using csrf-xhr in RubyOnRails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, elm

I'm building an application using RoR 5.1 and Elm. 
I need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/csrf-xhr in order to have Elm and RoR play nicely with the `protect_from_forgery` option on.
Right now it `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.`
I actually did copy the .js file into assets/ and used a  tag to include it, but I believe there are far better solutions.

I'm just not very used at the JS ecosystem, and I'd appreciate a hand because all my attempts ended in compilation errors, and I can see I'm pretty lost in all these new tools.

Comment: If you send the header `X-CSRF-Token` when making request, you will be good to go. Get the `<meta csrf..` value from html `<head>` using JS, and use port to pass it to Elm.

Comment: Perhaps, even easier, would be to use a flag to pass the token to Elm

Comment: I'd need to use a port. No, the lib I linked just needs to be imported and included after csrf_meta_tags. That definitely wasn't my question though, that problem has been solved already.

Comment: @ngw did you find the solution to your problem: details on how you solved it?